# Android: Random number decides players' turn

Tags: java, android, random, numbers, generator

I want to create a random integer between 1 and 2 (for player1 and player2). Then if it's 1, player 1 should win the first move, and if it's 2, player two should win the first move. I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int rand = generator.nextInt(2) + 1;

if(rand == 1){
    player1 = true;
    player2 = false;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerOneName + " won the first move!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
} else {
    player1 = false;
    player2 = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerTwoName + " won the first move!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

It doesn't give errors, but nothing happens. It's always player 1 that takes the first move, and the toast doesn't appear!

Comment: Where are you calling this piece of code? Toast also doesn't appear?

Comment: (int)(Math.random()*2+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first notice that your toast command is not complete, and should be:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerOneName + " won the first move!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

then you'll have a better look on what's what

Comment: Oh, dammit! :D Thank you very much Israel! :)

Comment: you won't believe how much it happens to me as well, just for being lazy for debugging

Answer (score 1):

To make the Toast show, you need to add .show() after creating it, i.e.

replace

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerOneName + " won the first move!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerOneName + " won the first move!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Yeah noticed that... Thanks krishan!